# Polarisation of a quadratic form on the space $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{k})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If the polarization $\overset{\sim}{q}(A,B)$ of the quadratic form $q(A) = \det A$ on the space $\text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{k})$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices over field $\mathbb{k}$ is defined as $\overset{\sim}{q}(A,B) = \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(AB^{\vee})$. I have to describe explicitly how to get $B^{\vee}$ from $B$.

This is my attempt:

We know, $\det B =\overset{\sim}{q}(B,B)= \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(BB^{\vee})$. If we let $B=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, and $B^{\vee}=\begin{bmatrix}e&f\\g&h\end{bmatrix}$, we get

$ad-bc=\frac{1}{2}(ae+bg+cf+dh) \implies a(e-d)+c(f+b)+b(g+c)+d(-h+a)=0$.

So, if I let $e=d,\ f=-b,\ g=-c,\ h=a$. I get $B^{\vee}=\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}=\det B \cdot B^{-1}$

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Depending on the context, you might want to argue why this solution is unique.

The matrix $B^{\vee}$ is, by the way, called the [*adjugate (matrix)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $B$. NB that the polarization formula does not apply when $\operatorname{char} \Bbb k = 2$.

Comment: Yes, uniqueness is something I am struggling with. Any hints or suggestions? 

Apologies for not writing that down. I had take it as a given that $\text{char}\ \mathbb{k} \neq 2$

Comment: Sure: Suppose some matrix $B'$ (again expressible in terms of the entries of $B$) has the same property. Then, use the linearity of $\operatorname{tr}$ and the fact $(C^{\vee})^{\vee} = C$ to show that $B' = B^{\vee}$.